# Any known Ubuntu issues on Acer aspire S3-391?

Tags: laptop, acer

I'm in the market for a new laptop to run Ubuntu 12.10 on -- I have my eye on a very reasonably priced Acer aspire S3-391 with a i7 chip and a hybrid drive.

Does anyone have a S3 and does it work okay... Any known issues?

I currently run Ubuntu 12.04 on a Acer Aspire One, which has constant suspend issues, so I am a little wary to go with the same manufacturer.

Answer (score -2):

I am running Ubuntu 12.10. Bluetooth doesn't work for me (though other people have got it working). There are some minor issues, but they are easy to fix.

There's more information at the [Linux Laptop Wiki](http://www.linlap.com/acer_aspire_s3-391).

Comment: This links to a different S3 variant (S3-951), which is the predecessor of the S3-391. While probably being similar, it's just not the same machine.